# What is the easiest way of iterating through 2 similar directory structures?

Tags: java

So for a project I have 2 directory structures. These directories are located at 2 different locations, where their respective directory structures and file contents are equivalent (just the contents of the files differ).

Now I would like to read through these 2 directory trees, creating "combos" of files that they contain.

An example for clarity; both directory trees look like this:

```
directory1
    directory2
        file1
        file2
    file3
    file4
```

Now I want to match both File instances of file1 from both directory trees.

The java File class only allows me to create a File[] array of its contents. Do I have to loop through the list it returns to find the matching File instances, or can I use a better method?

Comment: what do you mean by creating `combos` and matching `file instances`?

Comment: @John: Basically finding files with matching names. If in one directory there's a file like "foo.txt", I want to find the matching foo.txt in the other directory tree at the "same" place (e.g. the same relative path from the root of both directory trees).

Comment: Ok. silly me. When you do a listFiles() call on the File class you get a list that will be the same for both directories, as both directory trees are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just jot down here how I solved it:

```
public static File[] getDirectoryList(File file) {
    File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    });
    return files;
}
```

This code here gets all the subdirectories of a File istance. As both directory trees are equal, the File[] list returned will be the same for the corresponding 2 File intances from the file trees.

If you instead want to have all the files contained by the directory, change the line "return file.isDirectory();" to "return file.isFile();".

Comment: This is the method I ended up using, although Apache is also certainly worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use 3rd party jars, I suggest this:

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Otherwise, you have to write your own methods to iterate on folders recursively.

Comment: hm. I often see people refer to the apache stuff, though I never really used it myself. I've figured it out now using the regular java library, but thanks for the answer anyway.. I'll probably check out the apache stuff at some point to see what they got :)